# Помогите понять. SQL JOIN. Отсутствует уникальный столбец\ Данное выделение не содержит уникального столбца

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть вот такой кусок БД классного журнала и требуется  получить оценки студентов по ID явки.[image: БД] 
Составил вот такой запрос однако в нём нет уникального столбца а мне бы очень хотелось чтобы он там был для сортировки и поиска по столбцам. Гугл за 3 дня мне так и не помог)

Подскажите как можно его сделать или может следует улучшить Бд)

```
SELECT `id_student`,`znachenie` FROM `yavka` join `yroki` on `yroki`.`id_yavki`=`yavka`.`id_yavki` WHERE `yavka`.`id_yavki` = 5
```

Comment: Извините, мне не удалось понять ваш вопрос. Зачем вам уникальный столбец, где он нужен? Какую вообще задачу вы решаете? У вас возвращается какая то ошибка или что-то еще? Попробуйте сформулировать более понятно

Comment: судя по всему yroki.id_uroka

Comment: Мне необходимо имея id_yavki из урока, создать способ просмотра какие же оценки за этот урок получали студенты. В таблице явки используется суррогатный ключ т.к. на один урок создаётся одна явка в которой несколько студентов получают различные оценки.

Comment: Что то я не понял, как у вас вообще таблицы связаны. Откуда берется id_yavki. Я не вижу таблицы в которой бы он был первичным ключом.

Comment: id_yavki не является первичным ключом нигде, в таблице yavka он, по сути, является главным ключом т.е. все новые значения явок, отличаются от предыдущих как автоинкриментные и, по сути, ключевые, но там используется суррогатный ключ вместо составного первичного ключа (id_student + id_yavki). Сделано это для облегчения написания php кода для обращения к этим таблицам